# Checkbox selection in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with two checkbox columns. (column1 and column2)

column1 column2 column3 etc

I am trying to implement logic where users

- can't select checkbox from same row.
- They can select only one checkbox from column 1
- they can select as many as they want from column 2.

1 was easy to do

```
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
       var checkedValue = $(this).prop('checked');                          
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function ()
     {
 $(this).prop('checked', false);
                        });
  $(this).prop("checked", checkedValue);
     });
```

But after implementing step one, I am not able to do other two conditions. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use radio button  in column 1 (no jquery or javascript code nedeed. Radio buttons must have the same name)

you don't need any specific condition to implemente selection for the column 3.